# Android gradle androidDependencies command errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, azure-notificationhub, gradle-dependencies

So, when I run the androidDependencies command from Android Studio I get the following LONG output.  What do all the ERRORS mean?  It still builds successfully, should I do something about the errors and if so how do I go about cleaning them up?

**androidDependencies Output**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [androidDependencies]
:app:androidDependencies
debug
+--- LOCAL: notification-hubs-0.4.jar
+--- LOCAL: android-viewbadger.jar
+--- LOCAL: android-maps-extensions.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0
Error:+--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
\--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.5
debugAndroidTest
No dependencies
debugUnitTest
No dependencies
release
+--- LOCAL: notification-hubs-0.4.jar
+--- LOCAL: android-viewbadger.jar
+--- LOCAL: android-maps-extensions.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0
Error:+--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
Error:|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
Error:\--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
Error:\--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
\--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.5
releaseUnitTest
No dependencies
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 4.936 secs
Information:256 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**libs folder contents**

```
android-maps-extensions.jar
android-viewbadger.jar
notification-hubs-0.4.jar
```

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.MYAPPID.android"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.5@aar'
}




repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**COULD THIS SOMEHOW BE RELATED TO MY PROGUARD SETTINGS?**

Comment: Strange! Have never seen such thing..which gradle version you are using?2.13 or 2.14?

Comment: @Droidwala - going to File->Project Structure->Project->Gradle version shows 2.10, android Plugin Version is 2.1.0.

Comment: Could this somehow be related to my ProGuard settings?

Comment: Are you calling `gradle androidDependencies` or `./gradlew androidDependencies`? 
I think it's unlikely it's something to do with ProGuard, but you can very easily verify that, by disabling it.

Comment: have you tried "./gradle(w) :app:dependencies " and seen what it gives you as output... from: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide (seems to be superset of androidDep.. but with different exact info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment (but comment is too short)

I went ahead and made a new project and copied your app build.gradle and I get the following from `./gradlew androidDependencies`  so I believe that it has to do with with your static libs vs your dependencies (I obviously can't load the same .jar(s) that you have (and how you might have edited them))

My recommendation is to make a project like I did and then slowly add one jar at a time, and see which causes the errors. (without any code that actually relies upon any of the deps.) This might help you better identify the 'exact' root issue.

Edit: I also just noticed that my output has slightly different output than yours... because mine has `com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0`
 vs your `com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0` so I'm wondering if updating your stuff in the the SDK Manager might fix this for you.

```
 ./gradlew androidDependencies
:app:androidDependencies
debug
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0
|    |         +--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |              +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |              |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |              |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                        \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                             \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
\--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.5

debugAndroidTest
No dependencies

debugUnitTest
No dependencies

release
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0
|    |         +--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.0.jar
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |              +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |              |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |              |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |         |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                        \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                             \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    |                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.2.0.jar
\--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.5
```

Comment: so I decided to completely uninstall Android Studio and start fresh.  Started up fresh project, added my dependencies to the gradle.build and....same thing except this time more errors. Instead of 256 I get 2,046.  I think it has something to do with the Azure notification hub includes.

Comment: just noticed the extra errors come from me updating my play-services to 9.2.0.  When I leave it at 8.4.0, I get the same 256 errors

Comment: I am still having the same problem, however your answer was the most helpful and since I have to award the bounty to someone or it goes to waste, it's yours.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i'll preview some solutions you can try it

1- check yout proguard file and add this

```
# this belong gms
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

2- but although you need to update to latest versions

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

3- and add plugin after dependences block

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

4- finally in build.gradle file in project modul

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: thank you for your response, however this did not resolve the problem.  My error count went from 256 to 2,806 after adding step 1 and 2.  Step 3 and 4 I did not attempt because I have never used the google-services.json file in this app, and never had to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

For GCM, you don't need to add this one(compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0') in dependencies.

This('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0') one is enough for GCM, if you used [latest studio gcm sample](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/push-notification-using-gcm-in-android.html).

And also try remove all the gms play services ads,auth,etc except this one('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0').

com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 is enough for all gms play services related library.